# Wrong switch case syntax but works on all browser except Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, safari-web-inspector

Here's an example of what I meant

```
switch(fruits) {
    case fruits = "Banana":
        text = "Banana is good!";
    break;
    case fruits = "Orange":
    text = "I am not a fan of orange.";
    break;
    case fruits = "Apple":
    text = "How you like them apples?";
    break;
    default:
    text = "I have never heard of that fruit...";
}
```

Notice that the case syntax doesn't follow [official guideline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)

And it doesn't get any sort of warning in VSCode

The odd thing is, and something I hope someone would be able to answer me is: **Why does this code still works on all browsers except Safari?** And there's an additional interesting thing that happens in Safari as you can see below

---

This is how it works in **Chrome**
[image: chrome copy]

---

This is how it works in **Safari**
[image: safari copy]

---

And here's the weird part, if I turn on **Safari Web Inspector**, it works, but turn it off and it stops working
[image: safari webinspector copy]

---

So what's the reason this happens?

And here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xL742bfe/2/) for those who want to see the code in action yourself. Thanks, [w3 Schools for the sample code](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_state_switch1)

---

**EDIT:**
I am aware that the correct code is as follow, so to repeat the question, why does the above code still works on all browser except Safari when technically it should not work at all

```
switch(fruits) {
    case "Banana":
        text = "Banana is good!";
    break;
    case "Orange":
    text = "I am not a fan of orange.";
    break;
    case "Apple":
    text = "How you like them apples?";
    break;
    default:
    text = "I have never heard of that fruit...";
}
```

Comment: do you get an error in safari? can you try to wrap the assingment in parenthesis? does the change throws an error?

Comment: Just tried it `case (fruits = "Banana"):`, no difference

Comment: What is the value of knowing my a wrong syntax does or does not work? ... You are not going to use it anyway. Still, only each browser manufacturer could answer that properly, for the rest if us it will likely be a guess, and my guess is that Safar's internal _case_ evaluation simply make use of ["operator precedence"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) where _the assignment operator returns the value that is assigned (right-to-left assignment)_

Comment: Cause usually, if it's a wrong syntax, the code will not run at all in any browsers, but in this case, it does run on all except Safari and oddly enough, turning on Safari web inspector hides the problem.

And since this is the wrong syntax, technically it should not run on any browser at all.

Good point on the right-to-left assignment, that's possible.

Comment: You might also want to know that browsers doesn't work as with e.g. Windows development. If something fail in a browser, I will try its best to render/fix it anyway, so it won't end up with a blank screen.

Comment: @LGSon, oh I didn't know that the browser will try its best to render/fix the error. Thanks!